# how to define complete pseudo-riemannian manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry

In riemannin geometry, we define distance function by minimizing the length of curves. However we have nondefinite metric on psedu-riemannian manifold, so we cannot define a length of a curve as riemannian manifold
$$L(\gamma)=\int_a^b<\dot\gamma,\dot\gamma>^{\frac{1}{2}}dt$$
Then we also cannot define the distance function, and complete concept on pseudo-riemannian manifold.

So how we define a complete pseudo-riemannian manifold? Can we just substitute the length with
$$L(\gamma)=\int_a^b|<\dot\gamma,\dot\gamma>|^{\frac{1}{2}}dt$$

Any advice is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Hopf-Rinow says that global extendability of geodesics is one of the equivalent possible definitions of completeness. And you can extend this to pseudo-Riemannian manifolds, since the LC-connection still exists in this situation.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo So geodesically complete equals that $\exp_p$ can be evaluated for all $v\in T_pM$ in the pseudo-riemannian situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can presumably be done without the need for defining geodesic lengths.  Observe that the notions of connections and parallel transport are perfectly valid for pseudo-Riemannian manifolds, and therefore we have the notion of the exponential map $\exp:TM \to M$ given by $\exp(p,v) = \exp_p(v) = \gamma(p,1,v)$ where $\gamma$ is the unique geodesic starting at point $p$ with initial tangent vector $v$, and the geodesic evaluated at "time" $1$.  We can therefore define completeness of a pseudo-Riemannian manifold to mean that $\exp_p$ can be evaluated for all $v \in T_pM$.  Note that this is equivalent to geodesics being extended to all of $\mathbb{R}$ as the real parameter.

Comment: So geodesically complete equals that $\exp_p$ can be evaluated for all $v\in T_pM$ in the pseudo-riemannian situation?

Comment: @gaoxinge Correct.  This is equivalent to the concept of geodesics being extended to $\mathbb{R}$ as their domain because of the homogeneity property of geodesics.  You can check Barrett O'Neill's book on semi-Riemannian geometry if you're interested.